# Django Managemengt Command Logging Joins Messages

Tags: python, django, logging

When I issue log statements from a Django management command, they always get joined into one big log statement for the whole command execution. Instead, I want them to be issued individually line by line like usual application logs. That way log aggregation can pick them up properly and not as one extremely large message.

```py
LOGGING_ROOT_HANDLERS = ['prometheus', 'console']

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'json': {
            '()': 'pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter',
            'fmt': '%(levelname)s %(levelno)s %(pathname)s %(funcName)s %(asctime)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue'},
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'json',
        },
        'prometheus': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'app.logging_handlers.PrometheusHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': LOGGING_ROOT_HANDLERS},
        'myapp.management.commands': {
            'handlers': LOGGING_ROOT_HANDLERS.copy(),
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': LOGGING_ROOT_HANDLERS.copy(),
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': LOGGING_ROOT_HANDLERS.copy(),
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

```py
import logging

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        logger.info("Message %s", "1")
        logger.info("Message %s", "2")
```

Current output:

```
{"levelname": "INFO", "levelno": 20, "pathname": "runcommand.py", "funcName": "<module>", "asctime": "2020-06-03 09:32:19,497", "message": ""}
{"levelname": "WARNING", "levelno": 30, "pathname": "runcommand.py", "funcName": "<module>", "asctime": "2020-06-03 09:32:19,498", "message": "{\"levelname\": \"INFO\", \"levelno\": 20, \"pathname\": \"/www/app/myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py\", \"funcName\": \"handle\", \"asctime\": \"2020-06-03 09:32:19,345\", \"message\": \"Message 1\"}\n{\"levelname\": \"INFO\", \"levelno\": 20, \"pathname\": \"/www/app/myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py\", \"funcName\": \"handle\", \"asctime\": \"2020-06-03 09:32:19,345\", \"message\": \"Message 1\"}\n{\"levelname\": \"INFO\", \"levelno\": 20, \"pathname\": \"/www/app/myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py\", \"funcName\": \"handle\", \"asctime\": \"2020-06-03 09:32:19,345\", \"message\": \"Message 2\"}\n{\"levelname\": \"INFO\", \"levelno\": 20, \"pathname\": \"/www/app/myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py\", \"funcName\": \"handle\", \"asctime\": \"2020-06-03 09:32:19,345\", \"message\": \"Message 2\"}\n"}
{"levelname": "INFO", "levelno": 20, "pathname": "runcommand.py", "funcName": "<module>", "asctime": "2020-06-03 09:32:19,498", "message": "script \"python manage.py mycommand\" exited with 0"}
```

How can I make the second line 2 separate lines instead? I don't want the messages to be aggregated into one. - This even happens if I issue normal `print` statements from the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was running `python runcommand.py` - with `python manage.py` logging behaves like one would expect.